# How to access the current rails object id in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I am on a view, how can I access the ID of the ruby object that is currently represented by that view?

E.g. If I am on `blah.com/jobs/1` how do I get 1?

I thought about trimming the current URL but that seems way too brittle, especially given I have nested resources.  The only other easy way I can think of is to have a hidden field but it seems silly to have a hidden input on a show page where there aren't any forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right that parsing the URL is a bad idea, you're better off explicitly supplying it somewhere.

You could attach a `data-job-id` attribute to a standard element in the HTML, perhaps even `<body>`. Then your JavaScript could do things like this:

```
var id;
var $body = $('body');
if(id = $body.data('job-id'))
    // Do some job things.
else if(id = $body('user-id'))
    // Do some user things.
```

and you'd still be HTML5 compliant and you wouldn't have to muck about with hidden inputs.

You don't have to use `<body>` of course, your HTML probably has some top level container with a known `id` so you could use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest one of the following:

1. As Jamsi suggested, include `<%= params[:id] %>` or `<%= @job[:id] %>` directly in your javascript:

   `var id = <%= @job[:id] %>`
2. If your javascript is in a separate file, follow Mu's advice. Add the `<%= @job[:id] %>` to one of your view's html tags, and query it.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't just <%= params[:id] %> do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example, combining from the answers already provided.

Using the `params[:id]` and the body element, the following inline statement will produce a `data-params-id` attribute, that can be used generically in a layout file:

```
<body <%= "data-params-id=#{params[:id]}" if params.has_key?(:id) %> >
```

This can then be accessed with the following:

**JavaScript:**

```
var dataId = document.body.getAttribute('data-params-id');
```

**jQuery:**

```
var dataId = $('body').data('params-id');
```